# How to pass ajax response value with query string in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to pass an ajax result with query string in php. But i don't know how to assign ajax response in php variable.
 My code is

```
<script>
    function langchange()
    {
        var langs= $('#langs').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"ajax_lang_change.php",
            data:"id="+langs,
            success:function(value){
                var data=value.split("|_,_|");
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    $("#cat_desc"+i).html(data[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $(window).load(function(){
        langchange();
    });
</script>
```

I have to assign this value to $lang_id and pass it in the following query

```
<a href="category.php?c_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&lang_id=<?php echo $lang_id;?>"></a>
```

ajax-language_change.php

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM category AS c INNER JOIN category_language AS cl ON c.id=cl.category_id where parent_id IS NULL && lang_id='$id'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['category_description']."|_,_|";
}

?>
```

The result of this script is captured in ajax and assigned in #cat_desc. I have to assign this in php variable $lang_id

Help??

Comment: Your question requires more information. Are you asking how to assign a value to `$lang_id` ? What should be on `ajax_lang_change.php` to return to your ajax function `langchange()` ? or how to use the ajax response from `success:function(value)` ?

Comment: What is actually you'r #langs? Is it a `string`? If you add a `data: "string" + var`, you just got a string. Put you'r data in an `object` like `data: {langs: 'id' + langs};`

Comment: $("#lang_id".html(data[1]);

Comment: is there anyway to add this to php variable??